# How can we change angular-in-memory-web base url

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am new to angular and I was referring standard angular material present on angular site for the tutorial and I come upon part "Get Data from server". In this, I have created my in-memory dataservice like this.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero';
    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const data = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];

    return {data};
  }
}
```

And call it in my service class

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import {MessageService} from './message.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
        
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  constructor( 
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }
        
  private heroesUrl = 'api/data'; 
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
       
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched Heroes')),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
  }
}
```

so my question is can we change the base of web URI from api/data to test/data or demo/data something like that?

Comment: You want to return data from `InMemoryDataService ` instead of http request, but you need to do it like fetching it from web api right ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Technically the in-memory-api intercepts effectively all requests in the following url segment pattern `:base/:collectionName/:id?`. `:base` can really be anything and you can configure it be anything. That being said, is the issue URL configuration across different environments, dev api url vs production url?

Comment: yes. I got you that URI pattern would be like this :base/:collectionName/:id? so my question is can we change : base  from api to any random name like test or demo or anything like that. for in-memory-api  or it will take api  as base name by default?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. There is a `apiBase` property you can configure. In my test app I wanted to send requests to `/fake-api` instead of just `api` and this code helped:

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
  InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false, apiBase: 'fake-api/' }
)
```